# Should the “physics” tag exist?

Tags: discussion, retagging

Almost all sci-fi works have their own in-universe rules of physics. Is this tag useful?

Comment: I count 45 questions with the [tag:physics] tag, not two

Comment: Sorry. I counted that from my profile. :) Edited the question..

Comment: Ah, but does that now change your opinion about the question?

Comment: @Richard It's a question. It doesn't have any opinion.

Comment: Hmm. The way the question is now phrased, I can't decide whether to upvote or downvote. I definitely think it should exist but I'm strongly against you adding it to "thousands of questions".

Comment: @Richard How about this? Upvote if you think it's a useful question to ask, then upvote the "yes" answer or provide a different answer for others to vote on.

Comment: @besw - I don't want my upvote to seem like encouragement for his idea of adding lots of extra tags

Comment: @SS I've removed the part which makes this question only applicable to yourself - feel free to rollback.

Comment: @Mooz - In light of the update, I've changed my downvote to a neutral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, I think “physics” is a useful tag.**

A few notes:

- There are [46 questions in the tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics), so it’s clearly being used.
- The tag description is

  > Questions about the physics of a fictional universe.

  So while most fictional universes have their own specific physics, there are a lot of (if not most) questions that are asking about something that has nothing to do with physics, fictional or otherwise. Using this tag on those questions would be inappropriate.
- I think it’s a useful tag: it’s well-scoped, clearly on-topic and not something that would be easy to search for. (With the caveat that a question with this tag is only on-topic is about the fictional physics, and not looking for real-world scientific explanations.)

Comment: Nice answer. Add to your answer about two tag searches. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars+physics